# Type Support does not exist after upgrade to Xamarin.Forms 5

Tags: c#, visual-studio, xamarin, xamarin.forms, nuget

I've updated Xamarin.Forms Nuget package from 4.8.0.1560 to 5.0.0.1874. After this I got the following errors:

> The type or namespace name 'Support' does not exist in the namespace
> 'Xamarin.Android' (are you missing an assembly reference?)
> The type or namespace name 'Net' does not exist in the namespace
> 'MyProject.Android' (are you missing an assembly reference?)
> The type or namespace name 'Graphics' does not exist in the namespace
> 'MyProject.Android' (are you missing an assembly reference?)
> The type or namespace name 'App' does not exist in the namespace
> 'MyProject.Android' (are you missing an assembly reference?)

I've deleted bin and obj folders, clean and rebuild solution, but nothing.
Any suggestion?

Comment: check [the docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/release-notes/5.0/5.0.0). There are some breaking changes that you need to check

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The steps required to upgrade an app from Xamarin.Forms 4.x to 5.x are provided by Microsoft, here:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/troubleshooting/questions/forms5-migration